# Use the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem to conclude ${\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/ J \cong {\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/ K $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, group-homomorphism

Let $\alpha :\scr{F}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $\alpha(f)=f(1)$ and let $\beta :\scr{F}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $\beta(f)=f(2)$.

Let $J$ be set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ whose graph passes through the point $(1,0)$ and let $K$ be set of all functions whose graph passes through $(2,0)$. Use the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem to prove that $\mathbb{R} \cong {\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/J $ and $\mathbb{R} \cong {\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/ K$. Then conclude ${\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/ J \cong {\scr F}(\mathbb{R})/ K$.

I was able to prove that $\alpha,\beta$ were homomorphisms from $\scr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ using the basic properties of the functions as well as the definitions of onto and homomorphisms, however the extension to this problem has managed to thoroughly confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $J$ is the kernel of $\alpha$, so by the fundamental isomorphism theorem $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J \cong \alpha[\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})]$. Here $\alpha[\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})]$ means the image of $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ under $\alpha$. But assuming $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all functions on $\mathbb{R}$ this image is just $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J \cong \mathbb{R}$.

By an analogous argument $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/K \cong \mathbb{R}$.

It immediately follows that $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/J \cong \mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})/K$.